# How to type two variables that are correlated in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have a structure `ComboChartSpec` with `primary` and `secondary` fields. I'm defining a util function to process this `ComboChartSpec`.

If I define it in this way, it works

```
function process1() {
  const yAxisType = 'primary';
  const otherYAxisType = 'secondary';
  return {
    [yAxisType]: foo,
    [otherYAxisType]: bar
  }
}
function process2() {
  const yAxisType = 'secondary';
  const otherYAxisType = 'primary';
  return {
    [yAxisType]: foo,
    [otherYAxisType]: bar
  }
}
```

I want to merge these two functions. But I kept getting TS errors. How can I resolve it? Thanks!

```
function process(yAxisType: 'primary' | 'secondary') {
  const otherYAxisType = yAxisType === 'primary' ? 'secondary' : 'primary';
  return {
    [yAxisType]: foo,
    [otherYAxisType]: bar
  }
}
```

```
Type '{ [x: string]: { fields: never[]; } | { type: "quantitative"; }; scale: { type: "quantitative"; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ComboChartAxisEncoding<"editor">'.
  Type '{ [x: string]: { fields: never[]; } | { type: "quantitative"; }; scale: { type: "quantitative"; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ComboChartSingleAxisEncoding<"editor">'.
    Type '{ [x: string]: { fields: never[]; } | { type: "quantitative"; }; scale: { type: "quantitative"; }; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ primary: ComboChartSingleAxisSectionEncoding<"editor">; secondary: ComboChartSingleAxisSectionEncoding<"editor">; scale: QuantitativeScale; }': primary, secondaryts(2322)
index.ts(85, 3): The expected type comes from property 'y' which is declared here on type 'ComboChartEncodingMap<"editor">'
```

See [Minimal repro on TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=40&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCEC2AjCaAWAhrAIIgCWAzgKIB2AxhACbm0DmcAvOlrgcTADKrNgBtgZKnUYt2cAD48ceIrAAiAV0KjJNBsxEBuAFDHQkWAmSoMy-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-ZoAPllpao5aacD1ioBKreao4GpdcA7Xo+lM3APkBqCcBBZ4mjecAAPyXsGkZmi0V5IfKcCEKesr7oex77FBDpmvB4bWjBRrnje8rRj4aYZlmTAQJKtDNPAuZQHmAB0cAAHJuqg7o9HArBwJgiCaph-GZqeq4VMkOZQIQYCnqIbqnhAmwIJK8ANFkp5ckwB6EPQ+D-hp7rAJgcBEKe7pZtqUAaAkCbABxXy0YIEDNkJGkAJJwAxzHwEQ-QIBAmpEOwkmoPZjnxrGpkZqgABSgj-tgABWaKUF5+lwOlGjanAtDAMABkwGFxlcmwUX3JKXk8jmEAaHscBMq1cZHlArk+LGcVJtWbYlmBfbVgO9aNi2g0AV2w1VjWOx1qEE2LuO7IWpy3K8nOAyLjiQxAA)

```
export type ComboChartAxisEncoding = ComboChartSingleAxisEncoding | ComboChartDualAxisEncoding;

export type ComboChartSingleAxisEncoding = {
  primary: ComboChartSingleAxisSectionEncoding;
  secondary: ComboChartSingleAxisSectionEncoding;
  scale: 'quantitative';
};
export type ComboChartSingleAxisSectionEncoding = {
  fields: number[];
};
export type ComboChartDualAxisEncoding = {
  primary: ComboChartDualAxisSectionEncoding;
  secondary: ComboChartDualAxisSectionEncoding;
};
export type ComboChartDualAxisSectionEncoding = {
  fields: number[];
  scale: 'quantitative';
};

function process1(): ComboChartAxisEncoding {
  const yAxisType: 'primary' | 'secondary' = 'primary';
  const otherYAxisType: 'primary' | 'secondary' = 'secondary';

  return { // this works
    [yAxisType]: { fields: [] },
    [otherYAxisType]: { fields: [] },
    scale: 'quantitative',
  };
}
function process2<T extends 'primary' | 'secondary'>(yAxisType: T): ComboChartAxisEncoding {
  const otherYAxisType = (yAxisType === 'primary' ? 'secondary' : 'secondary') as (T extends 'primary' ? 'secondary' : 'primary');

  // this doesn't work. Note that in my case this function wraps lots of test cases and each of them has this structure.
  // So, if I don't have to change the structure of the JS objects, and just need to change the types, it would be better.
  return { 
    [yAxisType]: { fields: [] },
    [otherYAxisType]: { fields: [] },
    scale: 'quantitative',
  };
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Also a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help a lot. What is `foo` and `bar`? What is the type that needs to be satisfied? When I copy your solution into the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE5wgUwM7YBQCeAggB4zYAqBymAXIgORowC2AhqgQ4gD6PaYICACYcuASkQBvAFCJEQsNiiI4UABaZUATVLkqNRAF5ExMpWqZjRk01Ssx3APz9BIx4np2HnBgG45RFRMKBBUJFl5eQBtM31LAF16YDg4ABpAmLVNHT0LGiTEACMOQIBfGTKgA) I can't show the issue.

Comment: @AlexWayne The original code definition is very complex. Let me try to get a minimal reproducible example

Comment: This question is touching lots of weird places in TypeScript. First, correlated union types don't really work directly, see [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and resolving them "safely" requires a refactoring as per [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). But TS doesn't understand computed properties well as per [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948). (continued...)

Comment: (...see prev comment) Trying to work around both gives you [this](https://tsplay.dev/Na552N) but I doubt it's worth the effort and you should do something different or just use type assertions. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @AlexWayne I've updated the minimal repro.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for your pointers. I've updated the minimal repro code.

Comment: • Okay I looked and... the minimal repro is larger than it needs to be? The "dual axis" stuff seems to be unused.  Can't you reduce to [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/N9aa7N)? • With the new version the closest I can get is [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMLLdN), which still involves painful ms/TS#47109 and ms/TS#13948 refactoring. So you're going to have to do something different like a type assertion or a simple refactoring like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w6qqDW).  Does that now fully address the q? If so I can write an a, if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I tried minify the interfaces and indeed it was not minimal yet. I want to avoid `as any as ComboChartAxisEncoding` because it totally nullify the ts check. The process3 works but since there are lots of tests, updating each of them like that is a bit painful. I followed @ghybs's suggestion and used a util function to handle that. I think your links to related tickets are still very helpful in understanding the whole picture. Seems like there is no easy way to work around it just by defining types; we have to use some util function. Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, `foo` and `bar` are interchangeable values (type `ComboChartSingleAxisSectionEncoding<"editor">`?) for the primary and secondary axis. And depending on some condition, you swap them using a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) technique:

```
{
  [yAxisType]: foo, // yAxisType is either 'primary' or 'secondary'
  [otherYAxisType]: bar // otherYAxisType is the other one
}
```

TypeScript correctly infers the shape of the resulting object as long as the computed property names are *dead simple* string literals, like in your initial case where you directly assign `'primary'` or `'secondary'` literal values to `yAxisType` and `otherYAxisType` variables.

Unfortunately, this is no longer the case as soon as one of these computed property names is a *union* of literals, i.e. if it can have different values. In that situation, TS resorts to inferring a Record type (`{ [x: string]: something; }`), which may no longer satisfy your expected object shape.

```
function process1(): ExpectedType {
  const yAxisType = 'primary' as 'primary' | 'secondary'; // No longer a single literal, but a union of literals
  const otherYAxisType = 'secondary';
  return { // Error: Property 'primary' is missing in type '{ [x: string]: number; secondary: number; }' but required in type 'ExpectedType'.
    [yAxisType]: foo,
    [otherYAxisType]: bar
  }
}
```

In your case, an extremely simple solution consists in swapping the *values* (`foo` and `bar`), instead of the keys:

```
function process(yAxisType: 'primary' | 'secondary'): ExpectedType {
  return primarySecondarySwap(yAxisType, foo, bar)
}

function primarySecondarySwap<FooBar>(type: 'primary' | 'secondary', foo: FooBar, bar: FooBar) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'primary': return { primary: foo, secondary: bar };
    case 'secondary': return { primary: bar, secondary: foo };
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHpAxsCATAKuaBeKBvAKCijACcBLAWwENSQAuKAOwFdKAjCUgbiKgGcIiAPZNUtBszaceBAL4ECIpv2BQAZsOFRcABl7LVUdrR1QAjLwLqWTZOVElSwxBH79zACgCUjeEhQMLHw+QzUQAEE4cn5MSDMAcjIqCQSoan4oJIoaOjSAHyzBZXE83mIwqGFgAAsuAE0omLicIqFRUpAE8qhSCGAWUiZ8KAB6UdhSZ1JGAAVnSFJQLOTcrqgYqEoY-nImAHMN4dB4hLwoAG04RlUKA4BdRlYOLm4BdrEJJ+lXqDk09gsNR9ACOLHIfVQRygJ2gCX8QkCLQSADo+MQLpForEsI8NFoADTosajAB6AH5iRdqnVSI1sS08SZSHwFAprLZ7I4yC43PxPFjmlhGNkUnkoIUEsUOqlfLAEIi0C0QsQ+gMhk4xSAAMofTragDu1DAAqaOMgBPxwktzO8fFGACpKjSGmblbhBeacNhcKK1mlyW0SqkoCLVqkeuNiMQKXw1YNhoRo5dPYzGJprcTxrHk9Taq6GbjGMys2TKcQ5A7RvJFDY7MAHMNw3RdcGW0awAAeABiWgAQrQAHyeWFhnIhyXSz55S0Zxi94QD0g22jz-u0bwqgQG8jARA1KAjrCbpPRxAZOHNrqMeMa85X9OE95tyTMv49CoXoMyvI3-oJkYH2MWhLSnTpH20OQejZIA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've updated the question with the minimal repro. I guess yours should work. But since there are lots of test cases to update, if I can keep the JS objects untouched and only update the types, it would be better! Otherwise I need to manually change 30~40 test cases to use this `primarySecondarySwap`